# What is the geometric meaning of those vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

There are vectors a and b, and I need to prove that 
$$|a+b|^2 +|a-b|^2=  2 |a| ^2 +2|b|^2$$
and tell what is the geometric meaning of it....
I don't understand how to explain and solve it and what does it mean?

Comment: Draw each of these vectors as sides of squares and then compare the areas.

Comment: Or recall that $|v|^2=v \cdot v$ where $(\ \cdot \ )$ is scalar product and the solution should be apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that $|v|^2=v\cdot v$ and that the dot product is symmetric and bilinear we get...

$|a+b|^2 = (a+b)\cdot(a+b) = a\cdot a+a\cdot b+b\cdot a+b \cdot b =|a|^2+2a\cdot b+|b|^2$

Do the same for $|a-b|^2$ and add the results and you'll get your desired identity.

What does this mean geometrically?

Draw two vectors $a$ and $b$ (based at the same point). These vectors span a parallelogram. Notice that the vectors $a+b$ and $a-b$ are the diagonals of this parallelogram. Your identity says that the sum of the squares of the lengths of the diagonals is equal to the sum of the squares of the lengths of the sides of the parallelogram. (Kind of sounds like the Pythagorean theorem, right?)

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ are vector forces, $|a+b|, |a-b|$ are the sum and difference force vectors represented in a parallelogram. $ (a+b)\cdot (a+b) $ allows derivation of first result.

The result allows us to recognize the scalar magnitudes geometric relation just like an algebraic real number.

$$ (x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2  =  2 (x^2+y^2); \,\, \rightarrow |a+b|^2 +|a-b|^2=  2 |a| ^2 +2|b|^2$$